# Create subfolder, not affected by WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I have a WordPress site installed in the root. I have added an online store to this site in the subfolder /shop. In the /shop folder is an index.php file and this .htaccess file:

```
#/shop/.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?arg1=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?arg1=$1&arg2=$2 [L]
```

Some sample valid URLs are:

```
http://www.mysite.com/shop/
http://www.mysite.com/shop/clothes
http://www.mysite.com/shop/shoes
http://www.mysite.com/shop/hats
```

These URLs display just fine, **but the header is a 404** which causes problems with Google.

Here is the request header:

```
GET /shop/clothes/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mysite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.mysite.com/shop/
Cookie: __utma=152555369.2028364656.1389216381.1389279043.1389294490.4; __utmz=152555369.1389216381.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); wp-settings-1=editor%3Dtinymce%26hidetb%3D1%26libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26urlbutton%3Dnone%26wplink%3D1; wp-settings-time-1=1389277270; PHPSESSID=2df7073e57934fd781ab27c1c7b74245; __utmb=152555369.34.10.1389294490; __utmc=152555369; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_b2aba7eb0409bbc11fbbc4c2403dc2dc=admin%7C1389471226%7Cc07f299f80fe0ac1b15598636b08f66f
X-LogDigger-CliVer: client-firefox 2.1.7
X-LogDigger: logme=0&reqid=f7a4f2ac-3cfc-4a63-94e6-0b9233c7dfe6&
Connection: keep-alive
```

Here is the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 09 Jan 2014 20:21:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.8.8
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13
X-Pingback: http://www.mysite.com/xmlrpc.php
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 14381
```

In my /shop/index.php file I tried manually outputting the header with status 200, but it didn't fix the problem.

I tried adding the following to the root .htaccess file (WordPress's) but it didnt work:

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
```

In the root .htaccess file (WordPress's) I tried adding these commands before, after, and within WordPress's RewriteRules, but I still get the 404 header:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
```

The /shop folder and subfolders have 0755 permissions, the files have 0644 all with the same owner/group as the WordPress install.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: If for testing you rename WP .htaccess to something else, do you still get 404 headers?

Comment: Just tried, yes the 404 error still comes up after renaming /.htaccess to /.htaccessxxx

Comment: Hmm that means it is not because of WP but due to rules/code in `/shop`

Comment: You are right.  In /shop/index.php I removed these two lines, which stopped the 404 error:
`require __DIR__ . '/../wp-blog-header.php';
get_header();`

But now the page has no header, I will need to find another way to display it without duplicating code.
Thanks for your help.  Put this in an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test whether WP indeed is causing it:

- You can rename WP `.htaccess` to something else, and then check if you still get 404 headers.

If still getting 404 errors with WP .htaccess then it is most likely being caused by rules/code in `/shop/` folder.

Comment: As noted above, you are right. In /shop/index.php I had included these two lines to output the template's header: `require __DIR__ . '/../wp-blog-header.php'; get_header();` Removing them made the 404 error disappear (and tracing through the WP code I see why).  Now the page has no header/style, so I will need to find another way to display it.  Thansk again.